# How can i get some part of html using XPath?

Tags: php, xpath, get

I need to get some part of html pages using php XPath query (sorry im new to XPath).

example html page

```
<html><head>blah lines</head><body>

<div id="mytable">
<table><tr><td>table cell value</td></tr></table>
</div>

<body><html>
```

is there any way to get div contents of above example along with html tags using XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all, but i was need whole part including tags, so i solved as follows

```
$detail= $xpath->query("//div [@id='mytable']");
$querycontent = $detail->item(0);
$html->saveXML($querycontent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following xpath query will return the "mytable" div:

```
//div[@id='mytable']
```

`//div` will select all divs in the document
`[@id='mytable']` will return only matches with a "mytable" attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
/html/body/div[@id='mytable']
```